# Algebra with arctanh

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I want to show that
$$\text{arctanh }y=a\text{ arctanh }\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)$$
leads to 
$$1/x=\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^{\frac{1}{2a}}.$$

But I don't know what to do with the constant $a$. Can someone show me the steps please?

Comment: What is there to do with $a$? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use
$$
\tanh(x)=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}
$$
to get
$$
\newcommand{\arctanh}{\operatorname{arctanh}}
\arctanh\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)=u\implies\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}=\frac{e^{2u}-1}{e^{2u}+1}\implies u=\log(x)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\arctanh\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)=\log(x)
$$
Thus,
$$
\arctanh(y)=a\log(x)\implies y=\frac{x^{2a}-1}{x^{2a}+1}\implies\frac{1+y}{1-y}=x^{2a}
$$